# Using were along with she

Tags: subjunctives

I want to know if "were" and "she" can be used together.For example.

> If she were here, it would be more funny.

We use were for "you" and "I". Can we use it for "he" and "she".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the subjunctive 'were' for all pronouns such as he, she, it, they, we, etc. However, you have the tense of the following verb wrong. 'If she were here' refers to a hypothetical or wished-for present or future situation, so if you mean to talk about the present or future, you need 'if she were here, it would be more funny', or for the past, 'if she had been here, it would have been more funny'.

Comment: The original construction might be acceptable is some dialects. I'm not a native speaker, but I've definitely seen American and Australian speakers use it. Swan's *Practical English Usage* also mentions it. *Sometimes a simple past tense is used with **if** where a past perfect would be normal. This is more common in American English. If I knew you were coming I'd have baked a cake. / If I had the money with me, I would have bought you one. / If I didn't have my walking boots on, I think I would have really hurt my foot.*

Comment: Some dialects, yes, for example where I live (Bristol/West of England, but seen as 'yokel' by outsiders and the more educated), and "If I knew you were coming..." does not address the present case.

Comment: @athlonusm *If she were here, it would have been funnier* is a grammatical utterance and means that if something were true now (or in general), something in the past would have happened. The sentences Swan talks about there would all be grammatical in BrE, except that in BrE you'd probably *prefer* the past perfect for "dialectal reasons", and I'd defer to Swan's judgement there (I have no idea whether what they're saying is true, but it is a well-known book, so they might be onto something).

Comment: @userr2684291 1) Here's an example from *The Hunger Games*. The protagonist's father died five years ago. *My father **could have made** good money selling them, but if the officials **found out** he **would have been** publicly executed for inciting a rebellion.* 2) This also applies to the "I wish" construction: https://i.imgur.com/nDEpwdu.png

Comment: What has that got to do with the question, the use of the subjunctive?

Comment: @athlonusm You could ask about that example here on ELL. I think it's just sloppy writing, but maybe there's an explanation. It's unlike the Swan examples you quoted above, however.